# Can't install Vagrant box Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to install Laravel Homestead on Mac OS X following the official documentation instructions on [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).

I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant. Now I'm trying to add the Homestead box with the command `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`. After a while the download stops and I get an error. It doesn't let me restore the download so I have to delete the partial download file and start from zero. I've tried it many times.

I think my Internet connection has something to do since it's kinda slow and it's a large file.

Here's the complete code:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) virtualbox
2) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 1
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.7) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 935392411 bytes remaining to read
```

After retrying:

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you on a poor connection?

Answer (score 68):

**A.** Go to `.vagrant.d\tmp\` and delete the partial download file, then try again.

**B.** If that fails, you could attempt downloading the file manually using a browser or other tool. Once downloaded, you can import it using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead path/to/virtualbox.box`.

(*Edited:* Adds second answer from comments below.)

Comment: I've done that many times already. Do you know if there's another option?

Comment: Hmm, you could attempt downloading [the file](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box) manually using a browser or other tool. Once downloaded, you can import it using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead path/to/virtualbox.box`.

Comment: For me it only works the way Vogt suggests in the comments.

Comment: I struggled with this for ages, even downloading manually wouldn't work in Chrome, Safari or via a curl - but for some reason Firefox succeeded where the others failed.

Comment: @ChrisVogt but instead of a `.box` file it downloads the file `hc-download`

Comment: You can see how to download it manually using this link http://laravel.io/forum/05-06-2015-how-to-download-vagrant-box-manually

Answer (score 42):

Try this:
`rm ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*`or `rm -R ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*`

Then `vagrant up` again.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me - had some tmp files.

Answer (score 13):

Go to `C:\Users\YourUSERNAME\.vagrant.d\tmp` and delete all the files. Then type following command:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

Comment: Thanks for providing a Windows location for the temp files!

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead -c
```

Comment: Did you fail to read the question? In the question what you suggest is exactly what is failing to work and thus the question.

Comment: @ydobonebi the documentation for the flag '-c' states: "Clean any temporary download files". using this flag removes the files associated with the partial download in .vagrant.d/tmp/ before attempting to add the box. it is behaviorally equivalent to removing the contents of the .vagrant.d/tmp directory and then retrying to add the box.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Vagrant V2 then you can use the `--clean` flag when adding a box.

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --clean
```

> `--clean` - If given, Vagrant will remove any old temporary files from prior downloads of the same URL. This is useful if you don't want Vagrant to resume a download from a previous point, perhaps because the contents changed.

[Vagrant Documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/box.html)

Comment: It's worked. If I tried to download with **--insecure**, it's didn't work properly dude. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem and I just went to

Home --> .vagrant.d -->tmp

Now here one zip file will be there, please delete that one and your done.

Answer (score 1):

type

```
cd ~
```

then type

```
rm -rf .vagrant.d
```

That should get it done .

Answer (score 0):

I solve this editing the *.json* file in: `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index`
Delete the value of key `machines` like `"machines": {...}` to `"machines":{}`

Answer (score 0):

To download a file you have to add version and provider in the URL. For example for downloading precise64 First you need its URL which is https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

then you have to add version and provider afterwards, for our example the download URL would be.

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/14.04/providers/virtualbox.box

Then you have to add it locally from your vagrant file.

To add it locally to vagrant file use the following command

```
vagrant box add foo-box /path/to/vagrant-box.box
vagrant init foo-box
vagrant up
```

This will create the vagrantfile and you can configure the vagrant file.

Answer (score 0):

I was simply resuming the process a few times before it was finally done. I think that the main problem is with the internet connection, it falters here at my home. The cleanest way certainly would be what others already suggested plus moving somewhere with a stable connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a repository problem and sometimes depends on the vagrant version. Updating vagrant could work but if problems persist you have to try to use the archived vagrant versions.